# Is it guaranteed that a container will destruct existing objects during std::move?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;

    A() = default;
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v1;
    std::vector<A> v2;

    v1.emplace_back();
    v1 = std::move(v2);
    std::cout << "moved\n";
}
```

[The output is](https://godbolt.org/z/4zf543h6f):

```
~A()
moved
```

My question is: Can I rely on `std::move` to destruct elements inside `v1`? Or, in other words, is the output above guaranteed, or can I get:

```
moved
~A()
```

It would be surprising if the latter is possible, but I didn't find a definite answer, and didn't find anything explicit in the standard. That could happen if the move assignment operator is implemented with `std::swap` or similar, but I didn't find a solid answer regarding whether that's valid or not.

Comment: q.v. [`std::vector operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) for the move assignment.

Comment: `std::move` is not moving anything. The actual move is happening in `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While swapping would be a valid implementation for move assignment in general, standard library containers have extra requirements. [Table 73](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/container.requirements#tab:container.req-row-15-column-3-sentence-1):

> Expression: `a = rv`
> Return type: `X&`
> Operational semantics: All existing elements of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed
> Assertion/Note pre-/post-condition: *Postconditions:* `a` is equal to the value that `rv` had before this assignment
> Complexity: linear

So a swap wouldn't suffice, since that wouldn't move-assign to or destroy the original `v1[0]`